# Dynamically extend a Class

Tags: dart

I wonder if there is the possibility to dynamically extend a class, I'm new to Dart and I'm looking for something like this (please forget about the ${whatever} is just for illustration purposes):

```
class MyClass extends ${otherClass}
```

and let's say I'm trying to instantiate it from another function:

```
var myDinamic = new myClass<otherClass>
```

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In short: No.
Dart requires all classes to have a single superclass. What you are asking for is having a single class that changes its superclass *per instance*. That's not really a single class - it's impossible to say which members that class has because it is really a different class for choice of superclass.

Answer (score 0):

That a class extends another class can only be defined statically but not at runtime. The closest to that is probably configuring types with generic type arguments.

See also
- https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#generics
- http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/01/generics-in-dart-or-why-javascript.html

```
abstract class SomeInterface {}
class A implements SomeInterface {}
class B implements SomeInterface {}
class C<T extends SomeInterface> {
  T doSomething(T arg) { return arg; }
}
main() {
  new C<A>();
  new C<B>();
  // does NOT work
  // var t = A;
  // new C<t>();
}
```

but type arguments also need to defined statically. You can't use a variable as generic type argument.